# Casts in JPQL with EclipseLink

Tags: hql, eclipselink, jpql

Is it possible to use casts in JPQL? In HQL it seems to be supported

> cast(... as ...), where the second
>   argument is the name of a Hibernate
>   type, and extract(... from ...) if
>   ANSI cast() and extract() is supported
>   by the underlying database

source : [Hibernate reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

My target JPA provider is EclipseLink, so any EclipseLink specific solution is ok as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literal downcasts in EclipseLink JPQL are currently not supported, but might be if the following issue gets resolved : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=315087

Answer (score 3):

According to the specification of JPA/JPA2, JPQL is not supporting query casts.
However, the most recent EclipseLink Release 2.1.0 does have a propritary support for downcasts in JPQL and expressions, please look [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Release/2.1.0/JPAQueryEnhancements#Query_Casting_2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am searching here for literal casts. There is a related open bug now : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=315087

Answer (score 1):

It should be supported using JPA 2.1 `TREAT` operator.